# vs code not launching, config issue with launcher?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, launch

When I go to launch my .py code in VS Code I get an error to configure launch.json. Looking at the code for launch.json it has a warning ""Missing property "program" (40,9)"". This is the entire code, but I am also including a close up of the area that vs code seems to have a problem with.

Here is the close-up of the "problem area":

```
"debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
    {                        <----- this is the problem vs code is having
        "name": "Python Module",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
```

This is the whole code, in case you need a larger view of what's going on:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "PySpark",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "osx": {
            "pythonPath": "${env.SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit"
        },
        "windows": {
            "pythonPath": "${env.SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit.cmd"
        },
        "linux": {
            "pythonPath": "${env.SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit"
        },
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
    {                        <----- this is the problem vs code is having
        "name": "Python Module",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
        "module": "module.name",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Integrated Terminal/Console",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "null",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "External Terminal/Console",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "null",
        "console": "externalTerminal",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/manage.py",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "args": [
            "runserver",
            "--noreload"
        ],
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput",
            "DjangoDebugging"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Flask",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "fully qualified path fo 'flask' executable. Generally located along with python interpreter",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "env": {
            "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceRoot}/quickstart/app.py"
        },
        "args": [
            "run",
            "--no-debugger",
            "--no-reload"
        ],
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Flask (old)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/run.py",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "args": [],
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Watson",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/console.py",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "args": [
            "dev",
            "runserver",
            "--noreload=True"
        ],
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "remoteRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "port": 3000,
        "secret": "my_secret",
        "host": "localhost"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that the 'program' attribute is missing. If we look at that config,

```
{                        <----- this is the problem vs code is having
    "name": "Python Module",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
    "module": "module.name",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit",
        "RedirectOutput"
    ]
},
```

Sure enough, there is no 'program' attribute. It's required, so you should add it if you want to use that config.

The 'program' attribute must point towards the program to start debugging with. Examples: `"program": "${file}"` to debug the open file. `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/foo.py"` to debug foo.py in your workspace folder.

See more details in the documentation: https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Debugging

Comment: I don't see a complete answer here. You have found precisely the cause of the error, but not the solution. Can you point out which is the value of "program" when a module run is needed ?

Comment: This is not a complete answer.

Comment: The correct value of the 'program' attribute depends on what you want to debug, so I can't tell you how to fix it, but I added some typical examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did. It gave me the same error but (44,9) on the code right above it I seen `"program": "${file}"`.

I added that line in the section it was having an issue with in your case (40) and I put that code right above the `"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/.env"`, so mine looks like this now:

```
{
        "name": "Python Module",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "module": "module.name",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "env": {},
        "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
```

This seemed to repair my problem hope this helps someone.